# How can I get triggered alarms using PowerCLI?

Tags: vmware-vsphere, powercli

In vSphere Client on a VM host in the Alarms tab there is a view of Triggered Alarms.

How can I get those alarms using PowerCLI?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To find all vmhosts with alarm status = "red", I expanded on this.

```
#
# Find all hosts with triggered alarms in "Red" state
#
$esx_all = Get-VMHost | Get-View
$Report=@()
foreach ($esx in $esx_all){
    foreach($triggered in $esx.TriggeredAlarmState){
        If ($triggered.OverallStatus -like "red" ){
            $lineitem={} | Select Name, AlarmInfo
            $alarmDef = Get-View -Id $triggered.Alarm
            $lineitem.Name = $esx.Name
            $lineitem.AlarmInfo = $alarmDef.Info.Name
            $Report+=$lineitem
        } 
    }
}
$Report |Sort Name | export-csv "c:\temp\ESX-Host-Red-Alarms.csv" -notypeinformation -useculture
Invoke-item "c:\temp\ESX-Host-Red-Alarms.csv"
```

Answer (score 4):

this is what i use.

```
$esx = Get-VMHost $vmhost | Get-View
foreach($triggered in $esx.TriggeredAlarmState){
  $alarmDef = Get-View -Id $triggered.Alarm
  Write-Host $alarmDef.Info.Name
}
```

Comment: I had tried that but it never returned anything at all, while the "Triggered Alarms" view in vSPhere Client showed my triggered alarm. (I created a triggered alarm based on a VM being used more than 1% CPU over 30 seconds as a test alarm.)

Comment: You may need to look at the vm view in that case. I am not sure if vm alarms are included in the vmhost view.

Answer (score 0):

To expand a bit on [johnshen64](https://serverfault.com/users/47260/johnshen64)'s PowerCLI [answer](https://serverfault.com/a/520576/293440), I found Luc Dekens' [post](https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-PowerCLI-Discussions/Triggered-Alarm-Object/m-p/427311/highlight/true#M8694) on communities.vmware.com to be *very* helpful:

```perl
foreach($dc in (Get-Datacenter | where {$_.ExtensionData.triggeredAlarmState})){
    $dc.ExtensionData.triggeredAlarmState |
    Select @{N="Entity";E={Get-View $_.Entity | Select -ExpandProperty Name}},
        @{N="Alarm";E={Get-View $_.Alarm | Select -ExpandProperty Info | Select -ExpandProperty Name}},Time,OverallStatus,
        @{N='vCenter';E={$dc.Uid.Split('@:')[1]}}
}
```

... and I ended up using a variation of that:

```perl
foreach ($toplevel in    @(Get-VDSwitch    | Where-Object { $_.ExtensionData.TriggeredAlarmState.count -gt 0 }) +
                         @(Get-Datacenter  | Where-Object { $_.ExtensionData.TriggeredAlarmState.count -gt 0 })) {
    foreach ($alarm in $toplevel.ExtensionData.TriggeredAlarmState) {
        $localt = [System.TimeZoneInfo]::ConvertTime($alarm.time, [System.TimeZoneInfo]::Local)
        $entity = Get-View $alarm.Entity
        $alarmview = Get-View $alarm.Alarm
        Write-Output ("Alarm: At top-level entity $($toplevel.Name), $($entity.Name) went " +
                        "$($alarm.OverallStatus) at $($localt) for $($alarmview.Info.Name)")
    }
}
```

The idea is to loop through each top-level entity that the alarms could roll up to. I discovered through trial and error that `Get-VDSwitch` and `Get-Datacenter` covered what I needed. The other tricky part is to realize that the Entity and Alarm objects inside the alarm are *references* to the actual objects, so to get details about the actual item, you have to dereference it with `Get-View`.